# Close iPhone webapp

Tags: iphone, ipad, web-applications, mobile-safari

I want to just close or minimize (hide) full-screen iPhone web application.

How to do this? `window.close();` doesn't work.

Comment: Yes you can.. There is something called 'close.js'. It's here on github and works really good. :
https://github.com/eds1999/Close.js/

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You cannot quit the browser from JavaScript.

But you could try to make the browser crash... not that this would be a good idea.

Comment: Not even in full-screen state. I know it's a limitation for full screen apps, but that's the way it is. Also keep in mind that almost all native apps are also quit via the hardware button. 

I think only one of the games I played had an exit button.

Comment: Used to try being consistent with other platforms. The Birds (on Android) has at least quit confirmation and closing can be cancelled. My solution is to gray the quit button out and change its label to 'Click Home button instead' (for Mobile Safari only).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you would want to do this, but **you cannot**.